# Flutter windows file permissions

Tags: flutter, windows

I currently try to implement auto-update functionallity for my desktop application. On linux it worked fine for me to just replace the executable with the new version. However on windows the application seems to need specific permissions to delete the old executable. When trying the delete the folder I get this error:

```
PathAccessException (PathAccessException: Deletion failed, path = 'C:\Users\me\Documents\myApp\build\windows\x64\runner\Debug' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 5))
```

Is there something like permissions on android where the application first needs write access?

Comment: Hi there. I ran into an issue like this recently, it wasn't a permission thing at all. In my case, If I can remember I think I mistakenly created a folder a/b/c/name.txt and tried creating a file a/b/c/name.txt then on trying to create that file I got that error. I don't totally remember everything though.